# Arithmetic operators and function calling in C

Tags: c, operators, math

I'm not quite sure why I can't do

```
double a = (double) my_Function(45) / 2048 / 2340 / 90;
printf("%.4f",a); // prints out 0.00
```

But instead I have to use one more variable as:

```
double a = (double) my_Function(45);
double b = a  / 2048 / 2340 / 90;
printf("%.4f",b);  // prints out the correct value
```

Comment: Why are you casting to `float` instead of `double`?  And the 2nd cast in your second answer does nothing.

Comment: Am I allowed to ask why you're hard-coding these seemingly magic numbers of 2048, 2340, and 90? Perhaps you could `#define MAGIC (2048 * 2340 * 90)` or `const int MAGIC = 2048 * 2340 * 90` and just `((double) my_Function(45)) / MAGIC` to simplify things for the future. Or, if they're supposed to be separate constants, you could still use that technique to give them names that help others understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Both of these blocks of code should yield the same result (the "correct" value).  Are you sure that you've not made an error copying the code here?

Comment: In virtually all cases both versions of the code will produce exactly the same result. Either your compiler is broken, or (more likely) your description of the problem is inaccurate (fake code).

Answer (score 1):

What does my_Function return? Perhaps your answer is less than 10^(-4).

Comment: Actually it was a matter of order of operations, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Robert Dalton: In both of your cases the order is the same, so no, it is not a matter of order of operations.

Comment: @Robert: I ran your code in my own test prog. It didn't matter about order of operations. If the answer is too small (< 10^(-4)) you will get an output of 0.0000. It will not round.

Comment: @Robert: Try using printf("%g",a) to confirm

Answer (score -1):

It comes down to order of operations.

You basically are doing this in the first line

```
double a = (double)(my_Function(45) / 2048 / 2340 / 90);
```

Comment: +1 but you should probably mention the corrected version: `((double)my_Function(45)) / 2048 / 2340 / 90`

Comment: The type cast has higher precedence than any of the arithmetic operators.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Not true. Cast has higher precedence than division.

Comment: @Matt:  No, I mean higher precedence.  @Daniel:  Look at the list; the cast clearly has higher precedence than division.  Thus, in `(double) my_Function(45) / 2048`, the cast is applied to the result of `my_Function(45)`, and then the division is computed, which is the desired behavior.

Comment: @AndreyT: Because I can't vote on any of these comments, I thought it was a good idea have this whole conversation 'accepted'.